# Parsing json files of different schemas to different tables json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm receiving json files of different schema and have to dump them in sql data base.

The json files have the schema

```
{'type':'abc','data':{'column1':'x','column2':'y',.........}}
```

Corresponding to each type of schema I have a strongly typed class named similar to the type but with word 'Table' attached..

eg. 'abcTable' which has only the schema of json.data (column1, column2, ...)

So, what I can do is do a dynamic deserializing of the main json and then based on the type value do a strongly typed json parsing of the corresponding data

```
dynamic jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
if (jsonata.type=='abc')
{
var abcobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<abcTable>(jsondata.data);
}
```

Here I'm deserializing the object twice, so don't look like the right way of doing..

Also I have 25+ such schemas and a similar number of classes/tables

So, I will be using a lot of if / else if /else statements...

I would like to understand if there are other better ways of solving what I'm trying to do..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit, I've proposed code that avoids many if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usually, `JObject` is your friend:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var type = parsed.Value<string>("type");

if (type == "abc")
{
   var abcObject = parsed["data"].ToObject<abcTable>();
}
```

I order to avoid many ifs, you can use the follwing pattern:

```
public interface ITableType
{
    bool Match(string type);
    void Handle(JToken jsonTable);
}

public AbcTableHandler: ITableType
{
    public bool Match(string type)
    {
        return type == "abc";
    }

    public void Handle(JToken jsonTable)
    {
        var abcTable = jsonTable.ToObject<abcTable>();
        // other code
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var handlers = new[] { new  AbcTableHandler() };
// ...
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var type = parsed.Value<string>("type");
var handler = handlers.SingleOfDefault(h => h.Match(type));
if (handler == null) 
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find handler for " + type);
handler.Handle(parsed["data"]);
```

**EDIT:**
Adding multiple handlers:

```
var handlers = new ITableType[] { new AbcTableHandler(), new OtherHandler, etc.. };
```

or

```
var handlers = new List<ITableType>();
handlers.Add(new AbcTableHandler());
handlers.Add(new OtherHandler());
```

Comment: I think it would be handlers.FirstOrDefault, also how do I add another handler'XyzTableHandler' in var handlers, Tx

Comment: I found just one example of using new[]..
var StaffMembers = new[]
        {
            new Employee(20204, "Harry Fields", EmploymentStatus.FullTime, 16.85),
            new Employee(92857, "Jennifer Almonds",
    EmploymentStatus.FullTime, 22.25),
            new Employee(42963, "Sharon Culbritt", 
   EmploymentStatus.PartTime, 10.95)
        };
Please do let know how to add multiple handlers --Tx